# Траслитерация названий изображений в Joomla K2 вместо md5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

По дефолту в компоненте K2 joomla имена всех загружаемых изображений для материалов шифруются через md5. В результате имя файла - это хаотичный набор символов. Для решения этой проблемы существует плагин, который позволяет прописывать корректную транслитерацию для изображений. Данный плагин работает только с штатными расширениями К2 которые идут в комплекте с компонентом.

С сторонним расширением ясное дело плагин работать отказывается. Речь идет о расширении, которое удобным способом позволяет добавлять похожие статьи к материалам.

Это расширение пытается найти файл для превью материала с именем по дефолту `'media/k2/items/cache/' . md5("Image" . $XTlinkedItem->id) .'_' . item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImageSize') .  '.jpg';` и естественно ничего найти не может, так как такого файла не существует.

Насколько я понимаю вместо `md5("Image" . $XTlinkedItem->id)` нужно вызвать переменную из другого плагина (который отвечает за траслитерацию), либо значение бд. Либо решить проблему в обратном порядке, сформировав функцию во втором плагине. Сделать ни то ни другое у меня не получилось, так как знание php на уровне копипаста :(  Помогите пожалуйста!

Ниже фрагмент кода расширения, которое позволяет задать транслитерацию для изображений. Т

```html
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (file_exists(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_k2/lib/k2plugin.php')) {
    require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_k2/lib/k2plugin.php';
}
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/plugins/k2/econa/tables');

class plgK2Econa extends K2Plugin
{
    public $pluginName = 'econa';
    public $pluginNameHumanReadable = 'Econa';
    public $sizes = array(
        'XS',
        'S',
        'M',
        'L',
        'XL',
        'Generic',
    );
    public $properies = array(
            'imageXSmall',
            'imageSmall',
            'imageMedium',
            'imageLarge',
            'imageXLarge',
            'imageGeneric',
        );

    public function __construct(&$subject, $params)
    {
        $language = JFactory::getLanguage();
        $language->load('plg_k2_econa.sys', JPATH_SITE.'/plugins/k2/econa');
        parent::__construct($subject, $params);
        $this->pluginNameHumanReadable = JText::_('PLG_K2_ECONA_FILENAME_LABEL');
    }

    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$item, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        if ($context == 'com_k2.relatedByTag') {
            $plugins = new JRegistry($item->plugins);
            $image = $plugins->get('econafilename');
            if ($image) {
                $filename = JFile::stripExt($image);
                $extension = JFile::getExt($image);
                foreach ($this->properies as $key => $property) {
                    $item->$property = JUri::root(true).'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image.'_'.$this->sizes[$key].'.jpg';
                }
                $size = 'image'.$item->params->get('itemRelatedImageSize', '0');
                if (isset($item->$size)) {
                    $item->image = $item->$size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onK2PrepareContent(&$item, $params, $page = 0)
    {
        $plugins = new JRegistry($item->plugins);
        $image = $plugins->get('econafilename');
        if ($image) {
            $filename = JFile::stripExt($image);
            $extension = JFile::getExt($image);
            foreach ($this->properies as $key => $property) {
                $item->$property = JUri::root(true).'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image.'_'.$this->sizes[$key].'.jpg';
            }

            // K2 content module
            if ($params->get('parsedInModule')) {
                $size = 'image'.$params->get('itemImgSize', 'Small');
                if (isset($item->$size)) {
                    $item->image = $item->$size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onBeforeK2Save(&$item, $isNew)
    {
        // Get application
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();

        // Get the plugins data
        $plugins = new JInput($application->input->get('plugins', '', 'array'));

        // Get upload value
        $upload = $plugins->getCmd('econaupload');

        // Override default upload with our file
        if ($upload) {
            $application->input->set('existingImage', '/tmp/'.$upload);
        }

        // Get delete value
        $delete = $plugins->getInt('econadelete');

        // Override default delete
        if ($delete) {
            $application->input->set('del_image', '1');
        }

        // Proxy on before save event to content plugin since it contains all the logic
        $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
        JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'econa');
        $dispatcher->trigger('onK2BeforeSave', array($item, $isNew));
    }

    public function onAfterK2Save(&$item, $isNew)
    {
        // Get application
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();

        // Get input
        $plugins = new JInput($application->input->get('plugins', '', 'array'));
        $upload = $plugins->getCmd('econaupload');
        $delete = $plugins->getBool('econadelete');
        $filename = $plugins->getString('econafilename');

        // Cleanup tmp folder. K2 has already created the images
        $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload;
        if ($upload && JFile::exists($file)) {
            JFile::delete($file);
        }

        // Get current image information
        $image = JTable::getInstance('Image', 'EconaK2Table');
        $image->load(array(
            'resourceId' => $item->id,
            'resourceType' => 'com_k2.item',
        ));

        // Case 1: Delete
        if ($delete) {
            if ($image) {
                // Delete Econa image files
                if ($image->filename) {
                    foreach ($this->sizes as $size) {
                        $path = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image->filename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                        if (JFile::exists($path)) {
                            JFile::delete($path);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Delete database record
                if ($image->resourceId) {
                    $image->delete();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        // Case 2: Remove custom filename
        if (!$filename && $image && $image->filename) {
            $targetFilename = md5('Image'.$item->id);
            foreach ($this->sizes as $size) {
                $source = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image->filename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                $target = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$targetFilename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                if (JFile::exists($source)) {
                    JFile::move($source, $target);
                }
            }

            // Delete database record
            if ($image->resourceId) {
                $image->delete();
            }

            return true;
        }

        // Case 3: Apply custom filename
        if ($filename) {

            // Validate filename
            $filename = $this->validateFilename($filename, $item->id);

            // Set source and target filenames
            $targetFilename = $filename;
            $sourceFilename = null;
            $hash = md5('Image'.$item->id);
            if ($upload) {
                $sourceFilename = $hash;
            } elseif ($image && $image->filename && $image->filename != $filename) {
                $sourceFilename = $image->filename;
            } elseif ((!$image || !$image->filename) && JFile::exists(JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$hash.'_M.jpg')) {
                $sourceFilename = $hash;
            }

            // Rename files
            if ($sourceFilename) {
                foreach ($this->sizes as $size) {
                    $source = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$sourceFilename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                    $target = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$targetFilename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                    if (JFile::exists($source)) {
                        if ($this->params->get('keep_native_images', 1)) {
                            JFile::copy($source, $target);
                        } else {
                            JFile::move($source, $target);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // If filename has changed remove the old files
            if ($image && $filename != $image->filename) {
                foreach ($this->sizes as $size) {
                    $path = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image->filename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                    if (JFile::exists($path)) {
                        JFile::delete($path);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Keep extra large image so we don't break the image preview column in administration lists
            if (!$this->params->get('keep_native_images', 1)) {
                JFile::copy(JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$filename.'_XL.jpg', JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$item->id).'_XL.jpg');
            }

            // Save to database
            $input = array();
            $input['resourceId'] = $item->id;
            $input['filename'] = $filename;
            $input['extension'] = 'jpg';
            $image->save($input);

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function onAfterK2Delete($itemId)
    {
        // Get current image information
        $image = JTable::getInstance('Image', 'EconaK2Table');
        $image->load(array(
            'resourceId' => $itemId,
            'resourceType' => 'com_k2.item',
        ));

        // Delete files
        if ($image->filename) {
            foreach ($this->sizes as $size) {
                $path = JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image->filename.'_'.$size.'.jpg';
                if (JFile::exists($path)) {
                    JFile::delete($path);
                }
            }
        }

        // Delete database record
        if ($image->resourceId) {
            $image->delete();
        }
    }

    public function onAfterK2Close()
    {
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();
        $plugins = new JInput($application->input->get('plugins', '', 'array'));
        $upload = $plugins->getCmd('econaupload');
        $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload;
        if ($upload && JFile::exists($file)) {
            JFile::delete($file);
        }
    }

    public function onAjaxEcona()
    {
        if (!JSession::checkToken()) {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));
        }
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();
        if ($application->isAdmin()) {
            $user = JFactory::getUser();
            if (!$user->authorise('core.create', 'com_k2') && !$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_k2') && !$user->authorise('core.edit.own', 'com_k2')) {
                throw new Exception(JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_ACCESS_DENIED'));
            }
        } else {
            if (JFile::exists(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_k2/helpers/permissions.php')) {
                require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_k2/helpers/permissions.php';
                K2HelperPermissions::setPermissions();
                if (!K2HelperPermissions::canAddItem()) {
                    throw new Exception(JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_ACCESS_DENIED'));
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception(JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_ACCESS_DENIED'));
            }
        }

        $task = $application->input->getCmd('task');
        if ($task == 'process') {
            return $this->process();
        } elseif ($task == 'delete') {
            return $this->clean();
        } else {
            return $this->upload();
        }
    }

    private function upload()
    {
        // Get application
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();

        // Get input
        $key = $application->input->getCmd('econaKey');
        $upload = $application->input->getCmd('econaUpload');
        $file = $application->input->files->get('image');
        $path = $application->input->getPath('path');
        $path = str_replace(JUri::root(true).'/', '', $path);

        // Key is required
        if (!$key) {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_K2_ECONA_NO_UPLOAD_KEY_PROVIDED'));
        }

        // Ensure that file is an image
        jimport('joomla.image.image');
        $image = new JImage();
        if ($path) {
            $image->loadFile(JPATH_SITE.'/'.$path);
        } else {
            $image->loadFile($file['tmp_name']);
        }

        // Save path
        $savepath = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp';

        // Delete any previous uploaded file in tmp directory
        if ($upload && JFile::exists($savepath.'/'.$upload)) {
            JFile::delete($savepath.'/'.$upload);
        }

        // Upload depending on source
        if ($path) {
            $filename = basename($path);
            $extension = JFile::getExt($filename);
            $name = JFile::stripExt($filename);
            $result = JFile::copy(JPATH_SITE.'/'.$path, $savepath.'/'.$key.'.'.$extension);
        } else {
            $filename = basename($file['name']);
            $extension = JFile::getExt($filename);
            $name = JFile::stripExt($filename);
            $result = JFile::upload($file['tmp_name'], $savepath.'/'.$key.'.'.$extension);
        }

        // Check for upload/copy failure
        if (!$result) {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_K2_ECONA_COULD_NOT_UPLOAD_IMAGE'));
        }

        $upload = $key.'.'.$extension;
        $preview = JUri::root(true).'/tmp/'.$upload;

        $response = new stdClass();
        $response->preview = $preview;
        $response->upload = $upload;
        $response->filename = $name;

        return $response;
    }

    private function process()
    {
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();
        $key = $application->input->getCmd('econaKey');
        $upload = $application->input->getCmd('econaUpload');
        $id = $application->input->getInt('id');
        $x = $application->input->getFloat('x');
        $y = $application->input->getFloat('y');
        $width = $application->input->getFloat('width');
        $height = $application->input->getFloat('height');
        $rotate = $application->input->getCmd('rotate');
        $scaleX = $application->input->getCmd('scaleX');
        $scaleY = $application->input->getCmd('scaleY');

        if (!$id && !$upload) {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_K2_ECONA_NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED'));
        }

        $file = null;
        if ($upload) {
            $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload;
        } else {
            $table = JTable::getInstance('Image', 'EconaK2Table');
            $table->load(array(
              'resourceId' => $id,
              'resourceType' => 'com_k2.item',
          ));
            if ($table->filename) {
                $source = $table->filename.'_XL.jpg';
            } else {
                $source = md5('Image'.$id).'_XL.jpg';
            }
            $upload = $key.'.jpg';
            JFile::copy(JPATH_SITE.'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$source, JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload);
            $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload;
        }

        if (!$file || !JFile::exists($file)) {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_K2_ECONA_IMAGE_FILE_NOT_FOUND'));
        }

        $basename = basename($file);
        $extension = JFile::getExt($basename);
        $name = JFile::stripExt($basename);

        ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
        jimport('joomla.image.image');
        $image = new JImage($file);
        if ($rotate) {
            if (strpos($rotate, '-') === 0) {
                $rotate = abs($rotate);
            } else {
                $rotate = 360 - abs($rotate);
            }
            $image = $image->rotate($rotate);
        }
        if ($scaleX == '-1' && $scaleY == '-1') {
            $image = $image->flip(IMG_FLIP_BOTH);
        } elseif ($scaleX == '-1') {
            $image = $image->flip(IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
        } elseif ($scaleY == '-1') {
            $image = $image->flip(IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
        }
        $image = $image->crop($width, $height, $x, $y);
        $image->toFile(JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload);
        $image->destroy();

        $upload = $name.'.'.$extension;
        $preview = JUri::root(true).'/tmp/'.$upload;

        $response = new stdClass();
        $response->preview = $preview;
        $response->upload = $upload;

        return $response;
    }

    private function clean()
    {
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();
        $upload = $application->input->getCmd('econaUpload');
        $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/'.$upload;
        if ($upload && JFile::exists($file)) {
            JFile::delete($file);
        }
    }

    private function validateFilename($filename, $itemId)
    {
        $sourceFilename = trim($filename);
        $filename = JFilterOutput::stringURLUnicodeSlug($filename);
        if (!$filename) {
            $filename = uniqid('plg_k2_econa_');
        }
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('resourceId'));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__econa'));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('resourceType').' = '.$db->quote('com_k2.item'));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('filename').' = '.$db->quote($filename));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('resourceId').' != '.$db->quote($itemId));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();
        if ($result) {
            $filename .= '_'.uniqid();
        }
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if ($sourceFilename != $filename) {
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select($db->quoteName('plugins'));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_items'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('id').' = '.(int) $itemId);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $plugins = $db->loadResult();
            $plugins = json_decode($plugins);
            if (is_object($plugins) && isset($plugins->econafilename)) {
                $plugins->econafilename = $filename;
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);
                $query->update($db->quoteName('#__k2_items'));
                $query->set($db->quoteName('plugins').' = '.$db->quote(json_encode($plugins)));
                $query->where($db->quoteName('id').' = '.(int) $itemId);
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->execute();
            }
        }

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

Возможно нужен фрагмент кода в расширении в котором нужно получить значение с транслитерацией

```html
case 'item':
if ($item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImage', 0))
  {
  $imgi = JPATH_SITE .
  '/media/k2/items/cache/' .
  md5("Image" . $XTlinkedItem->id) . '_' .
        $item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImageSize') . '.jpg';

  if (JFile::exists($imgi))
    {
    $XTlinkedItem->image = JURI::root() .
    'media/k2/items/cache/' .
    md5("Image" . $XTlinkedItem->id) .
    '_' . $item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImageSize') .
       '.jpg';
    }
   }
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вроде бы как нашел решение...добавил к вопросу. подскажите корректно ли это ?

Comment: Решения лучше публиковать в ответах. Даже если не совсем правильные. Потом можно будет стереть, если найдутся существенные недостатки.

Comment: @D-side Понял, исправил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал вот так

```
case 'item':
                    if ($item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImage', 0))
                    {
// Get current image information
$image = JTable::getInstance('Image', 'EconaK2Table');
$image->load(array(
    'resourceId' => $XTlinkedItem->id,
    'resourceType' => 'com_k2.item',
));
                        $imgi = JPATH_SITE .
                            '/media/k2/items/cache/' .
                            md5("Image" . $XTlinkedItem->id) . '_' .
                            $item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImageSize') . '.jpg';

                        if (JFile::exists($imgi))
                        {
                            $XTlinkedItem->image = JURI::root() .
                                'media/k2/items/cache/' .
                                $image->filename .
                                '_' . $item_params->get('XTlinkedItemImageSize') .
                                '.jpg';
                        }
                    }
```

Работает, но Насколько это корректно ?